# Qt on Beaglebone Black

Tags: qt4, angstrom-linux, beagleboneblack

I am using the following this (http://www.cloud-rocket.com/2013/07/...or-beaglebone/) link for cross compliing on beablebone black.
But while following this link I encountered with following error after modifying the qmake.conf file

1) Modified qmake.conf details :

```
enter code here
# qmake configuration for building with arm-linux-g++
#

include(../../common/linux.conf)
include(../../common/gcc-base-unix.conf)
include(../../common/g`enter code here`++-unix.conf)
include(../../common/qws.conf)

# modifications to g++.conf
#Toolchain

#Compiler Flags to take advantage of the ARM architecture
QMAKE_CFLAGS_RELEASE = -O3 -march=armv7-a -mtune=cortex-a8 -mfpu=neon -mfloat-      abi=softfp
QMAKE_CXXFLAGS_RELEASE = -O3 -march=armv7-a -mtune=cortex-a8 -mfpu=neon -mfloat-abi=softfp

QMAKE_CC = /usr/local/angstrom/arm/arm-angstrom-linux-gnueabi/bin/gcc
QMAKE_CXX = /usr/local/angstrom/arm/arm-angstrom-linux-gnueabi/bin/g++
QMAKE_LINK = /usr/local/angstrom/arm/arm-angstrom-linux-gnueabi/bin/g++
QMAKE_LINK_SHLIB = /usr/local/angstrom/arm/arm-angstrom-linux-gnueabi/bin/g++

# modifications to linux.conf
QMAKE_AR = /usr/local/angstrom/arm/arm-angstrom-linux-gnueabi/bin/ar cqs
QMAKE_OBJCOPY = /usr/local/angstrom/arm/arm-angstrom-linux-gnueabi/bin/objcopy
QMAKE_STRIP = /usr/local/angstrom/arm/arm-angstrom-linux-gnueabi/bin/strip
load(qt_config)
```

2) error :

```
g++ -c -o project.o -pipe -DQMAKE_OPENSOURCE_EDITION -g -I. -Igenerators -Igenerators/unix -Igenerators/win32 -Igenerators/mac -Igenerators/symbian -Igenerators/integrity -I/home/harshal/Tool_chain\ setup/qt-4.8.5-beagle/include -I/home/harshal/Tool_chain\ setup/qt-4.8.5-beagle/include/QtCore -I/home/harshal/Tool_chain\ setup/qt-4.8.5-beagle/src/corelib/global -I/home/harshal/Tool_chain\ setup/qt-4.8.5-beagle/src/corelib/xml -I/home/harshal/Tool_chain\ setup/qt-4.8.5-beagle/tools/shared -DQT_NO_PCRE -DQT_BUILD_QMAKE -DQT_BOOTSTRAPPED -DQLIBRARYINFO_EPOCROOT -DQT_NO_TEXTCODEC -DQT_NO_UNICODETABLES -DQT_NO_COMPONENT -DQT_NO_STL -DQT_NO_COMPRESS -I/home/harshal/Tool_chain\ setup/qt-4.8.5-beagle/mkspecs/qws/linux-x86-g++ -DHAVE_QCONFIG_CPP -DQT_NO_THREAD -DQT_NO_QOBJECT -DQT_NO_GEOM_VARIANT -DQT_NO_DEPRECATED project.cpp
make: g++: Command not found
make: *** [project.o] Error 127
```

Can somebody help in solving the error?

Answer (score 0):

Appears to me that compiler is unknown. 
Did you correctly "installed" it as indicated ?:

> tar -C / -xjf angstrom-2011.03-i686-linux-armv7a-linux-gnueabi-toolchain-qte-4.6.3.tar.bz2

if you have missed the "-C /" this could be a reason as the qmake.conf refers to the path directly.

you can check with a :

```
 find / -name "arm\-angstrom\-linux\-gnueabi" 2>/dev/null
```

Answer (score 0):

You should have g++ on PATH. Make sure that g++ is accessible by calling:
 which g++